# Как с помощью CURL задать исходящий порт для соединения?

Tags: windows, curl, port

Необходимо, что бы команды всегда исходил из определенного порта, например `localhost:8080 -> 10.111.15.66:8888`

С подключением к порту 8888 проблем не возникает

```
curl.exe -I http://10.111.15.66:8888/out
```

Но каким образом можно задать исходящий порт 8080?

Я пытался использовать команды `--local-port` или `--resolve`, но curl все равно выбирал рандомный исходящий порт.

```
curl.exe -I http://10.111.15.66:8888/out --local-port 8080
```

Версия curl:

> curl 7.60.0 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.60.0 WinSSL zlib/1.2.11
>   Release-Date: 2018-05-16 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http
>   https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz

Comment: Попробуйте указать ключ `--local-port` первым, до `-I`.

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло. Использовал команду:  `>curl.exe --local-port 8080 -I http://10.111.15.66:8888`. Следил по wireshark: `TCP, Src Port: 6192, Dst Port: 8888, Seq: 0, Len: 0`.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить - а порт 8080 вообще-то свободен для использования?

Comment: Да, порты свободны. Я пытался использовать и другие порты, но результат тот же. Мне необходимо, что бы команда всего проходила по определенному порту в тестах я использую 8080